# Is it worth compressing analytics data on the browser before sending to server?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-analytics, http-compression, web-analytics-tools

When the javascript running in a client's browser is generating analytical data to send back to the server, at what point is it worth compressing the data before sending it to the server (if ever) ? Is there an established industry practice for this?

Comment: If you expect to be sending large, compressible data blocks with some frequency then it might be worth investigating.  I don't know of any industry standard practice for this.  Normally you try to keep the flow of data from the client to the server at a minimum, whenever possible.